# Change product_base programmatically

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I'm building a plugin that will be introducing and managing/handling a new product type (like Simple, Variable, etc), and I want to also change the `product_base` permalink from `product` to that new product type, ie. `property`.

But in the sense of building a whole plugin to handle all that, I also want to change the default `product_base` array key stored in `woocommerce_permalinks`.

The problem is I'm not sure what's the best place to hook my code to... If I hook it in `init` it'll be executed on every page load, so that's a total waste of resources... What's the best place to hook it? My code isn't something exotic, just a simple:

```
 if( $permalinks = get_option( 'woocommerce_permalinks' ) ) {
    $permalinks['product_base'] = 'property';
    update_option( 'woocommerce_permalinks', $permalinks );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your [plugin activation hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) to make the change. That will only run once, when your plugin is first activated, allowing the user to overwrite that change later (if they want to).

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, function () {
    if ( $permalinks = get_option( 'woocommerce_permalinks' ) ) {
        $permalinks['product_base'] = 'property';
        update_option( 'woocommerce_permalinks', $permalinks );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
});
```

If you want to always force the permalink settings, use the underlying WordPress hook `pre_update_option_$option_name`:

```
function wpse_406568_woocommerce_permalinks( $permalinks ) {
    $permalinks['product_base'] = 'property';

    return $permalinks;
}

add_filter( 'pre_update_option_woocommerce_permalinks', 'wpse_406568_woocommerce_permalinks' );
```

...that will always override whatever setting the user used for product base when saving their WC permalink settings.

Comment: `register_activation_hook` was indeed the place I was looking for... No need to force using the `product_base` I prefer... Thank you so much for your answer!